# using python, how to remove whole line in csv file if specific character is present in this line?

Tags: python, csv

I have large csv file, 216961 lines:

```
9808,54,43,59,999,17,10,59,999,-1,0,0
9809,54,43,59,999,17,12,0,-1,0,0
9810,54,43,59,999,17,13,0,001,-1,0,0
9811,54,43,59,999,17,13,59,999,-1,0,0
9812,54,43,59,999,17,15,0,-1,0,0
9813,54,43,59,999,17,16,0,001,0,0,0
9814,54,43,59,999,17,16,59,999,0,0,0
9815,54,43,59,999,17,18,0,0,0,0
9816,54,43,59,999,17,19,0,001,0,0,0
9817,54,43,59,999,17,19,59,999,0,0,0
9818,54,43,59,999,17,21,0,0,0,0
9819,54,43,59,999,17,22,0,001,0,0,0
9820,54,43,59,999,17,22,59,999,0,0,0
```

I need to sieve the file and remove all lines where -1 is present, about 6900 lines,
so I would like to ask for Your help

my attempt:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("file.csv", "rb"), delimiter=',')
for line in reader:
    match = line[7]
    if match not in '-1':
        print line
```

but -1 is not always at line[7]

Comment: Please post the code you tried.  Please ask specific questions on the code you tried.  So far, this is a few lines of Python using the `csv` module.  Please post some code that you tried that didn't work, so we know what kind of help you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this approach.

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("file.csv", "rb"), delimiter=',')
for line in reader:
    if "-1" not in line:
        print line
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have only one file, why not use vim?

```
:g/,-1,/d
```

If you have multiple files, you can try

1. Search for a line with ,-1,
2. Delete that line

Hints: look at fileinput

Comment: This fails for lines ending in ",-1"

Comment: Agreed. Fixing it is left as an exercise for OP. Hint: You can run global command (:g) multiple times.