# Remove a specific row in a csv file with python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to remove a row from a csv file if the 2nd column matches a string. My csv file has the following information:

```
    Name
15  Dog
```

I want the row with "Name" in it removed. The code I am using is:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open("info.csv", "rb"), delimiter=',')

f = csv.writer(open("final.csv", "wb"))
for line in reader:
    if "Name" not in line:
        f.writerow(line)
        print line
```

But the "Name" row isn't removed. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I was using the wrong delimiter. Changing it to \t worked. Below is the code that works now.
    import csv

```
reader = csv.reader(open("info.csv", "rb"), delimiter='\t')

f = csv.writer(open("final.csv", "wb"))
for line in reader:
    if "Name" not in line:
        f.writerow(line)
        print line
```

Comment: Your indentation is screwed up in your code example (no indentation after for-loop).  Could you fix that?  Since no rows are filtered out, you can assume that `"Name" not in line` is always evaluating to `True`.  Perhaps you could show us what the file actually looks like?

Comment: Sorry there is indentation, but it wasn't formatted correctly when I saved it. Just in case http://pastebin.com/9XwBkUx7 there it is as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems that you are specifying the wrong delimiter (comma)in csv.reader

Comment: +1.  This could be the cause of the the problem Howlin is describing, but I would be interested to see more detail from the OP because right now you're answering with a hunch.

Comment: The reason why I used a comma was because I was using the code from another question on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8566894/3204827) and assumed that I was to use it as well (I know a bad idea). I changed it from a comma to a \t and it works now. EDIT: I have added the code that works for me to the first post.

Answer (score 2):

Each line yielded by `reader` is a `list`, split by your delimiter.  Which, by the way, you specified as `,`, are you sure that is the delimiter you want?  Your sample is delimited by tabs.

Anyway, you want to check if `'Name'` is in *any* element of a given line.  So this will still work, regardless of whether your delimiter is correct:

```
for line in reader:
    if any('Name' in x for x in line):
        #write operation
```

Notice the difference.  This version checks for `'Name'` in each list element, yours checks if `'Name'` is `in` the list.  They are semantically different because `'Name' in ['blah blah Name']` is `False`.

I would recommend first fixing the delimiter error.  If you still have issues, use `if any(...)` as it is possible that the *exact token* `'Name'` is not in your list, but something that contains 'Name' is.