# Delete rows based on values in column in python

Tags: python

I am performing data clean on a .csv file for performing analytics. I am trying delete the rows having null values in their column in python.

Sample file:

```
    Unnamed: 0  2012    2011    2010    2009    2008    2005
0   United States of America    760739  752423  781844  812514  843683  862220
1   Brazil  732913  717185  715702  651879  649996  NaN
2   Germany     520005  513458  515853  519010  518499  494329
3   United Kingdom (England and Wales)  310544  336997  367055  399869  419273  541455
4   Mexico  211921  212141  230687  244623  250932  239166
5   France  193081  192263  192906  193405  187937  148651
6   Sweden  87052   89457   87854   86281   84566   72645
7   Romania     17219   12299   12301   9072    9457    8898
8   Nigeria     15388   NaN     18093   14075   14692   NaN
```

So far used is:

```
from pandas import read_csv
link = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets......csv"
data = read_csv(link)
data.head(100000)
```

How can I delete these rows?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have taken statistics for all all the countries for a condition. Would be performing analytics on this data. Before that, all the missing data that is if the value is 0 against the country for specific year, that particular country i would like to drop for analytics. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Suppose for a row of USA, if the amount is 0 in any of the year, i would like to drop USA. USA should not be present in the output. If for UK, all the values are not 0, then i will not be dropping that row. UK will be still there in the output

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468582/remove-a-specific-row-in-a-csv-file-with-python

It will help.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your data loaded you just need to figure out which rows to remove:

```
bad_rows = np.any(np.isnan(data), axis=1)
```

Then:

```
data[~bad_rows].head(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) method to remove these values. Passing in `how='any'` into the method as an argument will remove the row if *any* of the values is `null` and `how='all'` will only remove the row if *all* of the values are `null`.

```
cleaned_data = data.dropna(how='any')
```

**Edit 1.**

It's worth noting that you may not want to have to create a copy of your cleaned data. (i.e. `cleaned_data = data.dropna(how='any')`.

To save memory you can pass in the `inplace` option that will modify your original `DataFrame` and return `None`.

```
data.dropna(how='any', inplace=True)
data.head(100)
```

Comment: Here the number of rows will be dropped. But i need to drop rows based on the value. Suppose for a row of USA, if the amount is 0 in any of the year, i would like to drop USA. If for UK, all the values are not 0, then i will not be dropping that row. UK will be still there in the output.